# Проблема с Border при прижатом футере

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Сделал структуру с прижатым футером. Хотел сделать основному элементу рамку.
А при высоте более 100% все уезжает(как должно быть) а рамка **остается**. Основной элемент по высоте не растягивается.

**Код:**
http://jsfiddle.net/XNSZL/14/

```css
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    outline:0;
}
/* СТРУКТУРА */
 html, body {
    height:100%;
}
#Container {
    height:100%;
    min-width:1000px;
    max-width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
    border-left:1px solid #333;
    border-right:1px solid #333;
}
#Main {
    min-height:100%;
    margin: 0 0 -70px;
}
#All {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:70px;
}
/********************/

/* HEADER*/
 #Header {
    height:100px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #333;
}
#Header #a #logo {
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:90px;
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
#Header #a #logo span {
    color:#e00;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 1px #000000;
    font-size:50px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left:30px;
}
/********************/

/* FOOTER */
 #Footer {
    border-top:1px solid #333;
    height:69px;
    background:#FF0000;
    min-width:1000px;
    max-width:1000px;
}
#footerContent {
    padding-top:19px;
    padding-left:236px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
}
/********************/

/**************************************************************/

/* OUTER */
 #Outer {
    margin-top:20px;
}
/* LEFT BLOCK*/
 #LeftColumn {
    width:200px;
    background:#0f0;
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
    padding-left:50px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
/********************/

/* RIGHT BLOCK*/
 #RightColumn {
    margin-left:300px;
    margin-right:20px;
    background:#CCC;
    padding-right:20px;
}
/********************/

/** COMMON **/
 .clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
    <div id="Main">
        <div id="All">
            <div id="Header">
                <div id="a">
                    <div id="logo"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Outer">
                <div id="LeftColumn">=)
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>=)
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>=)
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div id="RightColumn">=)</div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Footer">
        <div id="footerContent">
            <p>Copyrights © ОАО FOOTER 2013</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Господа, почему так?

Answer (score 1):

Внутри `float` элементы, можно сделать `#containerу overflow:hidden`, чтобы вычислялась правильно высота.

Comment: Так он все обрезает. =(

Comment: Тогда overflow:auto

Comment: Получилось,спасибо. А причина такого расклада какая? Как float повлияли? И не будет ли потом каких либо последствий после Overflow?

Comment: Последствия такие,  что скроллы теперь к container блоку применяются а не к самому body. ОДин такой нюанс, но если подходит то и хорошо. проставьте тогда вопрос как верный.

Comment: Неа. плохой вариант вышел. Другие варианты есть? делаю же как то.

Comment: Чем плохой? Из-за скрола в контейнере? По-другому значит футер надо приживать, это другая задача. Марджин топ надо минусовой делать.